# VS 2008 Profiler - Caller/Callee view showing bottom of stack

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, profiler

I am currently trying to profile a class contained in a different assembly. To do this I created a small console application which calls into the public entry point of the class I want to profile. This enrty point is called Run().

This is working fine when I run my Console application in Debug mode and I can step into the Run() method. The Run() method calls a variety of other methods in its own assembly and other assemblies. However, when I create a new profiler of type "Instrumentation" in VS 2008, and run the profiler, the report shows my Main() function calling Run(), but in turn, when viewing the Caller/Callee report for my Run() method the report shows that the Run() method is the bottom of the stack.

This is clearly not the case - could anyone please suggest why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem which was solved by building the called assembly in the same output directory as the main service assembly. I didn't receive any warning messages associated with the profiler being unable to locate a called assembly in a different output directory - which seems to be an issue with the profiler.